# How to improve a pages performance with lots of images

Tags: performance, lazy-loading, cdn

I'm looking to improve a pages speed.
It has around 100 images on in, using Masonry JS for it's layout.

Would it be more beneficial to explore using lazy loading, or to use a CDN for the images?

EDIT:
The images vary between 50-130k. Approx 600px wide with varying heights. 72dpi.

The page currently hangs for ages, which is what I'm hoping to improve (15s load time average).

Comment: Use both lazy loading and CDN for images to improve performance.

Comment: Why not use both. Lazy loading from a CDN sounds like a winning combination...

Comment: The reason is the client. I need to pick one to recommend over the other, at least initially.

Comment: What kind of image? Resolution? Photos? File size?

Comment: The two are separate, lazy load doesn't load the image until it is scrolled in the viewport making the `initial` load of the page faster. Whereas the CDN image will be cached and be able to load noticeably faster when requested. So it would depend what your specific needs are?

Comment: Edited question with more info

Comment: If it is initial load time of 15s then go for lazy load if you have to pick just one for now

Comment: [Don't guess it - test it](https://aerotwist.com/blog/dont-guess-it-test-it/).  We can't tell you what the best option is, because you've not given us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `loading` attribute with all the images, and then use a [CDN](https://pagecdn.com) to serve images near instantly during scroll to give an impression of images being already available. The browser will do everything else. You don't even need a javascript lazyload library to handle this.

```
<img src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/browser-logos/chrome.png" loading="lazy" />
```

However, this feature is supported in only Chrome at the moment and will land in Edge Soon. For browsers that do not recognize the loading attribute, CDN will still speed up the image delivery if the user has enough bandwidth to parallelize the image delivery.